# How to disable HDMI port?

Tags: windows, display, hdmi

Is it possible to disable the HDMI output in Windows, so that, when you connect an HDMI device, the system doesn't react to it?
There's usually a second screen connect via HDMI, but I just want it to show information when I need it. Now, it always shows a part of the screen, so I have to switch to "Only this pc" in the Project (Windows+P) menu. That asks too much time, as I have to do it each time.
So, is it possible to disable the HDMI output and, if so, how?

Comment: No, it's not really possible for the PC to guess what you want or don't want at all times.

Comment: Funny how nobody seems to have understood thw question, but people still replied. As far as I understand you need a quick way of disabling or re-enabling the hdmi port on your computer so that you can easily activate it when you need it. Not a BIOS dependent solution that takes longer time. Im looking for the same thing. Did you find something?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to disable an HDMI port since it's kernel/driver controlled _(it's not like a USB port that can be turned off at the OS level)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but answering for anyone that needed it as I did!

If you have it, the **Nvidia Control Panel** will allow you to select which monitor you would like to use and deselect those you are not using!

If you use a different GPU perhaps there is a Graphics Card Controller that does the same.

Fantastic in my case for switching from my work monitor to my Tv when needed without pushing the graphics card to run both at once.

Comment: I don’t think that will do what OP wanted. Windows will remember display layouts with known displays, but if a new HDMI display comes around it will probably still be automatically activated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack,but it might work.
If you bought a 2 port HDMI switcher.
You could have the switch set on 2 until you need the port.

Anything on port 1 would be invisible, and port 2 would be empty so windows won't detect anything.

Now that means buying a hdmi switcher, but only you can decide if you want to go that far.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and later (possibly earlier), monitor configurations are persisted. So you can connect the monitor, got to display settings, under Multiple Displays choose `Disconnect this display`, and then monitor will remain disconnected whenever you connect the HDMI - until you change the settings again.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to disable it permanent your answer is in the computer BIOS.
You have to access your computers BIOS and set the HDMI Device state to Disabled of Off.

Cheers!

Comment: This isn’t a universal solution. It’s only possible with some firmware. It’s also only possible with integrated graphics.

Answer (score -2):

As above, the BIOS settings allows you to set the state of your HDMI device. The easiest way to get there is from the Settings app on your PC (assuming Windows 10). Choose **Update and Security > Recovery > Restart Now (under Advanced setup)**. Your computer will restart and show a blue screen with an option called **Troubleshooting**. Click that, then go to **Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart**.

> 1. Navigate to settings. You can get there by clicking the gear icon on the Start menu.
> 2. Select Update & security.
> 3. Select Recovery from the left menu.
> 4. Click Restart Now under Advanced startup. The comptuer will reboot to a special menu.
> 5. Click Troubleshoot.
> 6. Click Advanced options.
> 7. Select UEFI Firmware Settings.
> 8. Click Restart. Your system will restart and take you to the BIOS.
>      [How to Access the BIOS on a Windows 10 PC from Laptop Mag](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10)

There is also a keyboard shortcut you can use to go straight to BIOS when you first boot your PC. A list of these can be found [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/enter-bios-computer/).

Comment: Please include all relevant information from linked pages in your post. That way, the answer will stay complete even in the future when other resources become unavailable.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the bios. I am a blind user and cannot use the pc's bios...

Comment: @JordyDeweer - No.  If the firmware has the ability to disable the HDMI port, then it is going to be in the firmware, but honestly the reason you want to disable the HDMI port in the first place isn't clear.